# Simplify sql query for getting single data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

To start with, my database structure looks like below

```
Table Application:ID(pk), App_num, App_name, App_owner, App_sec
Table App_runner: ID(pk), app_id(FK:APP.id), runner_name
Table Jar_used:   ID(pk), runId(FK: App_runner.id),jar_name, time_stamp
Table Jar_static: ID(pk), jar_name, current_version, version_status(either of C,S,D)
```

My required resultset is as follows:

```
 App_Num, App_Name, App_Owner, Compliance
```

where `Compliance` is derived column based on `version_status` from `Jar_static` table as 'C'=Current, 'S'=Supported and 'D'=Deprecated.

Also the result set conditions are:

`app.id=app_runner.app_id` and
`app_runner.id=jar_used.runId` and
`jar_used.jar_name=jar_static.jar_name`

Following query works fine for me:

```
select app.APP_NUM, app.APP_NAME ,app.APP_OWNER , case jars.version_status 
 when 'C' then 'CURRENT' 
 when 'S' then 'SUPPORTED' 
 else 'DEPRECATED' 
end as COMPLIANCE 
from Application as app, app_runner as runner, jar_used as used, jar_static as jars 
    where app.id = runner.app_id and 
    runner.run_id = used.app_run_id and 
    jars.jar_name =used.jar_name
```

Can somebody please suggest a simplified way to do the same?
Also a likely requirement is to find records where `jar_used.jar_name='abc'` along with the other three conditions. Adding one more and can give the result but I am looking for some simplified way.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Some idiot downvoted my question. Surprised!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your query is fine.  You need to go through all four tables to get the information you need.  The query is not particularly complicated.

One note, however.  You should learn proper join syntax.  It makes queries easier to read, is more powerful, and helps prevent errors:

```
select app.APP_NUM, app.APP_NAME ,app.APP_OWNER ,
       (case jars.version_status 
          when 'C' then 'CURRENT' 
          when 'S' then 'SUPPORTED' 
          else 'DEPRECATED' 
        end) as COMPLIANCE 
from Application as app join
     app_runner as runner
     on app.id = runner.app_id join
     jar_used as used
     on runner.run_id = used.app_run_id join
     jar_static as jars 
     on jars.jar_name =used.jar_name;
```

EDIT:

The right way to use this query for a particular jar is to add a `where` clause:

```
select app.APP_NUM, app.APP_NAME ,app.APP_OWNER ,
       (case jars.version_status 
          when 'C' then 'CURRENT' 
          when 'S' then 'SUPPORTED' 
          else 'DEPRECATED' 
        end) as COMPLIANCE 
from Application as app join
     app_runner as runner
     on app.id = runner.app_id join
     jar_used as used
     on runner.run_id = used.app_run_id join
     jar_static as jars 
     on jars.jar_name =used.jar_name
where jar_name = 'abc'
```

If the query seems complex to you, you can put it into a view:

```
create view vw_application_jar as 
select app.APP_NUM, app.APP_NAME ,app.APP_OWNER ,
       (case jars.version_status 
          when 'C' then 'CURRENT' 
          when 'S' then 'SUPPORTED' 
          else 'DEPRECATED' 
        end) as COMPLIANCE,
       jar_name
from Application as app join
     app_runner as runner
     on app.id = runner.app_id join
     jar_used as used
     on runner.run_id = used.app_run_id join
     jar_static as jars 
     on jars.jar_name =used.jar_name
```

Then you can just use:

```
select *
from vw_application_jar 
where jar_name = 'abc';
```

Comment: thank you for your help. However can you please suggest something on the last condition. Is there any other way rather than adding one more 'and' where jar_name='abc'?

Comment: your query helps and works same as mine. Thank You. Can you please suggest how can I get the latest from ap_runner based on runner.app_id, in the same query ofcourse. My requirement has changed to get the latest record if there are more than one record, based on latest app_runner. Thanks for your help.